# Pleased and satisfied. What's the difference?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between 'pleased' and 'satisfied'?

The dictionary says:
'She was very pleased with her exam results.'
'The boss should be pleased with you.'

But I think I can say:
'She was very satisfied with her exam results.'
'The boss should be satisfied with you.'

Am I right?

And can we say 'a pleased customer'?
If we can - 'a pleased customer' is more happier than 'a satisfied customer'?

Comment: In effect, pleased means happy, and satisfied means content.  If you look up the meanings of happy and the meanings of content, you should understand the difference.

Comment: Could you give me some examples to clear see the difference, please.

Comment: I am pleased with the turnout at the party. I am satisfied with the turnout at the party. Pleased means happy. Satisfied means a sufficient number have come.

Answer (score 4):

*Pleased* is the word I would use to indicate a personal feeling of enjoyment and satisfaction, whereas I would use *satisfied* to indicate intellectual acceptance or acknowledgement of sufficient conformity to a particular standard.

Comment: +1  Selio, they are interchangeable to a certain extent but eg "Ladies and gentlemen, I am pleased to introduce our guest speaker..." - you would never substitute 'satisfied' here.

Answer (score -1):

Pleased is a word similar to happy, but has a slightly deeper feeling.

Satisfied has way more feeling than pleased.

*He was **pleased** that Harry answered his question* = He felt glad that Harry answered his question

*He was **satisfied** with the answer Harry gave him* = He felt strongly happy with Harry's answer.

Pleased is a synonym of glad as seen above. If you are pleased, you are happy but it doesn't mean you have gotten what you **really** wanted. Satisfied is when you **have** got what you **really** wanted.

Comment: You do not understand what "satisfied" means.