# Difference: "pleased", "satisfied" and "content"

Tags: differences, adjectives

We're trying to translate a psychological test and in its 30-some questions, there are three that are a little bit confusing, mainly because they translate to the same set of words according to our dictionaries. Since the original language of the test is English, I think they must make sense and difference to the native speaker.

We also found a few useful clues in the question titled 
[Pleased and satisfied. What's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159252/pleased-and-satisfied-whats-the-difference) and went on with a thesaurus, but we're still not confident enough.

So what's the actual difference here?

- I feel pleased
- I feel content
- I feel satisfied

All within the same test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pleased -- more of an emotional state, an inner feeling of satisfaction, often relates to something recently accomplished .. as in pleased with the outcome or result of some act.

Content -- happy with my status quo, with things as they are, I don't need more or to do more.  My present state is just fine.

Satisfied -- could be emotional or physical.  Either way, I have enough, happy with the results.  Might relate to something I've done or what others have done.

Comment: That's completely clear, thanks. However we are going to have a hard time putting this into Hungarian!

Comment: Hello, Doug. Answers that are preferred on ELU have supporting evidence. Can you provide any?

Answer (score 2):

The great Groucho Marx once gave a good funny example of the difference between satisfied and contented:
Two man were arguing about the question: what's the difference between satisfied and contented?

One man said: "there is no difference".

The other man said: "well, there is".
And he says:
 "Right now I am satisfied when my wife is at home with another man, but I'll be damned if I'm contented.